# Let $x^3 = y^2 + 1 = (y+i)(y-i)$. Why is $y+i$ a cube?

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $x^3 = y^2 + 1 = (y+i)(y-i)$. $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I am not sure how to go about showing how $y+i$ is a cube (i.e. $y+i = (a+bi)^3$). I'm not sure if it has something to do with norms or such.

Comment: you should state the question in a cmplete manner

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1:** compute the GCD of $y+i$ and $y-i$.

**Hint 2:** if $(y+i,y-i)\ne1$, then show $y$ is odd; thus, $y^2+1\equiv2\pmod8$.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting as well is that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a UFD

Comment: Really that $\mathbf Z[i][x,y]/(x^3-y^2-1)$ is, which is more subtle.